# Sum up different arrays into a new array

Tags: numerics, summation, list-manipulation

I have a question regarding sums in arrays.

So I have the following array:

```
list=RandomReal[{0,1},{5,2}]

(*{{0.693551,0.447185},{0.274842,0.637526},{0.745271,0.0288363},{0.894933,0.937219},{0.605447,0.0337067}}*)
```

And from that I want to have the splitting for each pair like that

```
Subsets[Range@Length@list, {2}]
{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}}
```

Lets say every array in the list is a pair of x and y coordinates.
Now I compute the distance between the different points using:

```
dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[list, {2}] .
```

But now I want to have the sum of all the distances where particle 1 is occuring, so these are the first 5 entries in the array, for particle 2 its the first and the 5, 6 and 7th etc.

In the end I want to have a list containing 5 arrays with the sum for each particle.

So can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DistanceMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) and use `Total` with the upper part of the matrix:

```
rowtotaldistances = Total[UpperTriangularize[DistanceMatrix[#],1],{2}]&

m = Partition[Range[0,10],2];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  2 & 3 \\
>  4 & 5 \\
>  6 & 7 \\
>  8 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
 TeXForm @ MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[DistanceMatrix[m],1]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 4 \sqrt{2} & 6 \sqrt{2} & 8 \sqrt{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 4 \sqrt{2} & 6 \sqrt{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 4 \sqrt{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
rowtotaldistances @ m // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{20 \sqrt{2},12 \sqrt{2},6 \sqrt{2},2 \sqrt{2},0\right\}$

**Note:** Using `{2}` as the second argument of `Total` gives the row totals:

```
mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {5, 5}];
TeXForm@MatrixForm[mat]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm[Total[m, {2}]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{1,4}+a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}+a_{2,3}+a_{2,4}+a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,1}+a_{3,2}+a_{3,3}+a_{3,4}+a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,1}+a_{4,2}+a_{4,3}+a_{4,4}+a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,1}+a_{5,2}+a_{5,3}+a_{5,4}+a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

For column totals leave the second argument out (or use `1` as the second argument):

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm[Total[mat]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a_{1,1}+a_{2,1}+a_{3,1}+a_{4,1}+a_{5,1} \\
>  a_{1,2}+a_{2,2}+a_{3,2}+a_{4,2}+a_{5,2} \\
>  a_{1,3}+a_{2,3}+a_{3,3}+a_{4,3}+a_{5,3} \\
>  a_{1,4}+a_{2,4}+a_{3,4}+a_{4,4}+a_{5,4} \\
>  a_{1,5}+a_{2,5}+a_{3,5}+a_{4,5}+a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Okay, thanks but if I do that now with 

rowtotaldistances = Total[Most @ UpperTriangularize[DistanceMatrix[list],1],{2}]

I just get 4 entries, but I have 5 particles

Comment: @Armani42, removed `Most` to get a 5X5 distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but now I have another problem, now I have

```
ener[r2_] = 4* (1/r2^12 - 1/r2^6);
```

And I want to make now

```
dist = DistanceMatrix[list, DistanceFunction->(#1-#2 &)];
```

Which produces me 2x2 vectors in a matrix.
But now I want to do that

```
e = Apply[ener @ {##}&, dist, {2}];
```

But here is the problem, that some entries in the vectors are 0 and dividing by zero is not possible.

So how can I avoid that maybe by an if statement or something like that?

Comment: @kglr do you have an idea for that problem? :)